# Authentication for Both windows and Unix users

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, kerberos, openldap

We have Active directory to authenticate users for windows machines. We have nis to authenticate linux users. These users are using both windows as well as Linux. They are using two different credentials for windows and Linux environments. Now we are planning to implement centralized users management for both Linux and windows users. So that we have track of them and maintain single credentials for all machines and application. If we create user in Active director it should sync in Linux as well. How company's will handling this kind of environments ? Please suggest. So that i will plan to implement the same.